# ionic 2 serve: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: ionic-framework

I ran into this problem when trying to test my ionic 2 script. When running `ionic serve -all`, the following error occured:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

My ionic 2 setup is as follows:

- Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
- Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.48
- ios-deploy version: Not installed
- ios-sim version: Not installed
- OS: Linux 4.4
- Node Version: v6.9.1
- Xcode version: Not installed

Any solution to this issue?

Comment: are you sure its not an error in template?

Comment: The only thing I did: downloaded a fresh 'blank' project yesterday, made some changes to the html page, the moment I hit save, the error pops up in my console.

Comment: thats what I am asking ? This error comes when there is a parsing error in template. Check your html again.

Comment: The only thing I did: 
1) downloaded a fresh 'blank' project yesterday, 
2) made some changes to the html page.

The moment I hit 'save', the error pops up in my console.
The browser doesn't update the change too (localhost:8100)

Comment: add your html page

Comment: <ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
     <ion-title>
        Ionic Blank
     </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
Test.
<p>
If you get lost, the <a href="http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2">docs</a> will be your guide.
</p>
</ion-content>

Comment: Dont see anything wrong in it. try ``npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev``  and check if ``ionic serve`` works.

Comment: Did that. Still the same. My ionic info is as follows:

Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4

Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8

Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4

Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.48

ios-deploy version: Not installed

ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v6.9.1
Xcode version: Not installed

Comment: what do you see in the browser?

Comment: The browser will show the default 'blank' project template.

Comment: The moment I perform an update / change to the html and hit 'save', the error appears, but the change is not reflected in the browser.

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem.
Did you have change the structure of directory like [image]

you should change it back!!